# How can I optimize webpack dynamic import 5,000+ modules

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

In my case, use Vue with vue-cli-service

When I use 'vue-cli-service serve' meet heap size out error

Then I found 5,000+ .json in webpack-dev-server and some code dynamic import it.

e.g. await import(`@static/json/{name}.json`)

I think It makes heap size out error.

Because webpack dynamic import get all modules then filter it.

How can I optimize..?

split directory?